# Retrieve navigation class name on page load jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of links that link to sections within the page using anchor tags. I'm trying to grab the current class name initially when the user loads the page and add the class of "active" to the list item. So for instance, if a user goes to www.mydomain.com/#about-section, the navigation will remove the existing 'active' class and then add the class to the current link.

```
 <nav id="primary">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#intro-section">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#work-section">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about-section">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact-section">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

How would I go about changing the class depending on which section is in view using jQuery?

Comment: Are anchors ids or links with names? `<div id="a" />` or `<a name="b" />`

Comment: The corresponding sections are like `<section id="intro-section" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you'd just bind "click" handlers to the `<a>` tags.

```
$('nav').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
  $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

If your nav structure is deeper or more complicated or whatever, you'd need to use more specific selectors.

*edit* — if you want to have this happen upon page load, you'd have to do something in a "ready" handler:

```
$(function() {
  $('nav a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

*edited* — the code above originally added "active" to the `<a>` instead of its parent `<li>` - thanks to @scessor for the correction.

Comment: For the "ready" handler: the "active" class should be first removed and then added (to the `li`!).

Comment: Well @scessor I guess so but I imagined that on a freshly-loaded page there'd be no "active" class applied anywhere.

Comment: Ok, in the html code above it's seems to be static, but you are right, it shouldn't. But you add the active class to the `a` tag not to the `li`.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly you get an URL Like:
 `var URL = www.mydomain.com/#about-section`
 you can get the anchor tag by:

```
 var anc =  URL.split('#')[1]; // 'about-section'
```

then you can get the  link with the href:

```
var aLink = $('a[href='+anc +']');
```

finally remove all active class get the li and add the active class

```
$('li','#primary').removeClass('active');
    aLink.closest('li').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would do the trick. Not tested.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash != '') {
    //remove active class
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    //attach active class to anchor
    $('a [name="' + hash + '"]').addClass('active');  //link anchors
    $('* [id="' + hash + '"]).addClass('active');     //id anchors
}
```